# Change Title/Label of an Activity in Android 5 recents screen

Tags: java, android, google-apps

With Android 5, Google supports multiple activities in the recents screen for a single application.
I managed to implement multiple activities in the recents screen with [this](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html) official doc.
How can I change the title of the activity? Switching to recents screen always shows my app name as title.

```
Activity.setTitle("title");
```

changes the title on the toolbar, but I want it to change in the recents screen, just like Google does in Google Chrome App.

I need to change the title programatically.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your activity you can use new method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.secondary_layout);
    setTaskDescription(new ActivityManager.TaskDescription("Activity 2"));
}
```

[setTaskDescription](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setTaskDescription(android.app.ActivityManager.TaskDescription)) sets information about activity in recents task list. In this example only title.

Comment: Thank you. Works like a charm! Just found out that you can pass parameters for icon and colorPrimary.